# Rest API Python Request: Response[400]

Tags: python, rest, request

I'm creating a python script that allows me to store and updating a client into the database. This is my code trying to store and update a client.

```
data = {"first_name": "Client 1", 
        "last_name": "Last1", 
        "address": "12 Street", 
        "phone_number": "9876543210", 
        "email": "client_1@test.com", 
        "password": "testtest", 
        "vehicles": [], 
        "deleted": False}

response = session.post('http://localhost:3000/api/client/register', json = data, verify = False )

data = {"_id": "602b5dbf4b610a0012fbd5e8",
        "first_name": "Client 1",
        "last_name": "Last1",
        "address": "10 Street",
        "phone_number": "9876543210",
        "email": "client_1@test.com",
        "password": "testtest",
        "vehicles": [],
        "deleted": False}

response = session.put('http://localhost:3000/api/client', json = data, verify = False)

print(response)
```

`http://localhost:3000/api/client/register` is where the client register. `http://localhost:3000/api/client` is where we can see all the client's database. Every time I try to update the client's data, I keep getting `<Response [400]>`. I know it means that the parameters are not inputted properly, but I don't see where. Can some please help me solve this???

Comment: Did you tried to print `response.json()` most likely it will contain the field validation errors

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM it printed {'message': 'An error occured!', 'error': "Cannot read property 'id' of null"}